# how to push to github without sync local/remote repo

Tags: git, github

I've a git folder in my pc that contains directory called work.
Each 10mn a file will be generated and added to work directory.

I need to push to github the new file generated in my work dir each 10mn then my automation script will remove it from my local work dir.

The problem is I'll only get the last file on my github each 10mn and not all of them.

what i want is:

```
#at t=10
file1 added to work git directory.
push it to github 
delete it from work dir

#at t=20
file2 added to work git directory.
push it to github 
delete it from work dir

#at t=30
file3 added to work git directory.
push it to github 
delete it from work dir


then i'll have test1, test2 and test3 on github (this is what i want, but i get only file3 now or the last push file).

The file add & deletion works perfectly and done with my automation script. My only problem is the one i mentioned above.
```

Comment: git does not work like this. You probably see only the last file because you commit the entire state of working directory which is _everything else than last file removed_. Sounds like git is not the right tool for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: http://www.xyproblem.info

Comment: thank you!! so you have any other place that i can store my files in (i should use command line for upload)

Answer (score 0):

Git does not work with files—not the way you're thinking, that is.  Git does not even work with *folders full of files*, although this is closer.  The issue here is that Git works with *commits*.  The `git push` operation pushes some *commits*.  Your repository on your local PC stores *commits* and your (separate) repository over on GitHub stores *commits*.  So you must think in terms of commits, not files.

Each commit acts like an *archive of all files*.  That is, given some commit—they're numbered—you ask Git to *extract* that commit, and Git gets the *full archive of every file* as stored in that commit.

If you make a commit on Tuesday, and that commit contains files `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, then Tuesday's commit contains files `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`.  It contains *those* files, *in the form they had when you made the commit*.  It contains *exactly those files* **forever**.

If you make a different commit on Wednesday, and that commit contains files `f3`, `f4`, and `f5` (but not `f1` or `f2`), that commit contains those files, in that form, *forever*.  It *never* contains `f1` and `f2`.

The commits act as *snapshots*, holding every file, frozen in time.  That's the #1 most important point of any version control system: it lets you "go back in time" and see what all your files looked like on Wednesday.  These files are literally frozen: you can't write to them, and not even Git can write to them.  To save space—among other reasons—Git stores them in a special format where only *Git* can *read* them too: they're compressed and, importantly, *de-duplicated* so that if Wednesday's files include all of Tuesday's files, they don't take any extra space for the duplicates.

Now, obviously, to get any work done, you can't use a frozen-in-time set of files.  So that's not how you *do work* with Git.  Instead, you tell Git: *extract a commit so that I have usable, read-able, write-able files*.  You pick the commit—usually the *latest and greatest* of course—and Git extracts *all* those files.

You should not *remove* files unless you want the *next* commit to explicitly *lack* those files.  Git will store the next commit's re-used copies of today's files without taking any space, if they're all duplicates.  Removing files won't save any space because they're stored *forever* in the *old* commits.

So that's what's going on here: you're making each commit as an archive of *one* file, omitting all the previous files.  Extracting the latest archive gets you just that one file.  If that's not what you want, stop doing that.

Comment: thank you!! so you have any other place that i can store my files in (i should use command line for upload)

Comment: Well, you have a choice: use a version control system and store *everything* for all time, or, use something else. There are a whole lot of "something else"-es, such as Amazon S3.